# Keep Android alertDialog on top - Xamarin C#

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, android-alertdialog

I searched for hours for a simple solution, nothing to do with the answers found here. The issue was in the Intelisence failing the programmer.

to keep the alert on top simply use SetCancelable(false);

```
    private void ShowMessage(string title, string message)
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        // Add the buttons events
        builder.SetPositiveButton("Yes", (Alert_YesClick));
        builder.SetNegativeButton("No", (Alert_NoClick));
        // Set other dialog properties
        builder.SetMessage(message);
        builder.SetTitle(title);
        builder.SetCancelable(false);

        // Create the AlertDialog
        AlertDialog dialog = builder.Create();

        dialog.Show();
    }

    private void Alert_YesClick(object sender, DialogClickEventArgs e)
    {
        var uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(_castingWeb);
        var intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView, uri);
        StartActivity(intent);
    }

    private void Alert_NoClick(object sender, DialogClickEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Please allow this to be set as an answer where ever it might be needed.

Comment: As far as I can read you found the solution. Please answer your own question and mark it as answered.

Comment: Not enough reputation

Answer (score 0):

Again to keep the alert on top simply use SetCancelable(false);

I hope this helps others.